# nth term test for divergence - help

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\dfrac{n}{n+1}\right)^n$$

to show that this diverges should I use the $n^{th}$ term test?

So far I have substituted infinity for $n$. Could I use L'hopital's rule to then show that this series diverges?

Comment: Yes, your limit is of the type $1^\infty$, so you can use L'H to calculate it and show it is not 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT** As $k \to \infty$, we have $$\left(\dfrac{k}{k+1} \right)^k = \dfrac1{\left(1+ \dfrac1k \right)^k}\sim e^{-1}$$

Comment: yes, this is clearly the right way to go. I made a dumb error in my "root test" computation; in fact, now I see I misread the question...

Comment: Your last approximation is wrong ;)

Comment: @N.S. :) Thanks.